# Wordpress tag auto close

Tags: wordpress, tags, wordpress-theming

Wordpress corrects the html markup in posts and also in template specific files.
I'm working on a template and what I'm trying to achieve is wrap a div in `<a href"#"></a>` tag.

Before the foreach loop there is  placed, then some more php and html markup and right before the foreach loop ends I paste in the ending tag .
What wordpress doeas it automatically adds the ending tag right after a href string tag, removes the correctly placed ending tag making the link empty.

He're is what I type:

```
    <li <?php if (get_option('square_portfolio_filter') != "true") { ?> data-id="id-<?php echo $count; ?>" data-type="<?php foreach ($terms as $term) { echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term->name)). ' '; } ?>" <?php ; } ?>>
<a href="#">
    <div class="thumbs-animate">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail(array(255,191), array('title' => ''.get_the_title().''));
        }
        ?>  
        <div class="details">
            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
            <p><?php content('15'); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php 
            if(get_option('square_view_project_link')!="") {
            echo get_option('square_view_project_link');
            }else {
            _e( 'View Project', 'square_lang' ); 
            }                                       
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</li>
```

And here is what Wordpress ends up saving:

```
    <li <?php if (get_option('square_portfolio_filter') != "true") { ?> data-id="id-<?php echo $count; ?>" data-type="<?php foreach ($terms as $term) { echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term->name)). ' '; } ?>" <?php ; } ?>>
<a href="#"></a>
    <div class="thumbs-animate">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail(array(255,191), array('title' => ''.get_the_title().''));
        }
        ?>  
        <div class="details">
            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
            <p><?php content('15'); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php 
            if(get_option('square_view_project_link')!="") {
            echo get_option('square_view_project_link');
            }else {
            _e( 'View Project', 'square_lang' ); 
            }                                       
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I temporarily fixed the issue using some javascript code but its neither good practice nor what I want to have:

```
onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink();?>';" style="cursor:pointer;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="#"><div>...</div></a>` is invalid HTML. You're not supposed to have a block-level element (`div`) inside of an inline element (`a`). WordPress is likely trying to protect you from that.

I can't tell if using `#` as your `href` is part of the actual code or just something you did for simplification, but if that is the actual code and you're attaching an `onclick` or something to the `a`, you could instead attach that to the `div` and it would work just as well.

Comment: I'm attaching onclick trigger on my div which solves the problem, but the inline js is not proper style so I wanted to make the div become a link by using html markup only

Comment: You can make a `div` accept a `click` event without resorting to inline scripting, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener -- or if your site has jQuery, http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I agree, even listener would do but I wanted to omit js if possible;)

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to comment that wrapping a block-level element is inside an inline element is perfectly fine in HTML 5.

`<a href="#"><div>...</div></a>` is valid html 5.